# What is "WriteCallback" in C++ for Arduino?

Tags: c++11, arduino

In a library I use, there is a WriteCallback type. I don't know what is it, I cannot find it define anywhere ?

Could someone explain me what is WriteCallback ? Is it a native function or type in c++ ?

.h file

```
#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
  #include "Arduino.h"
#else
  #include "WConstants.h"
#endif

typedef void (*WriteCallback)  (const byte what);    // send a byte to serial port
typedef int  (*AvailableCallback)  ();    // return number of bytes available
typedef int  (*ReadCallback)  ();    // read a byte from serial port

void sendMsg (WriteCallback fSend, 
              const byte * data, const byte length);
byte recvMsg (AvailableCallback fAvailable, ReadCallback fRead, 
              byte * data, const byte length, 
              unsigned long timeout = 500);
```

Comment: Simply put this is a pointer to a function which takes const byte as one and only parameter. This is mainly used to pass functions which will act as callbacks. Take a quick look https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/callbacks-in-c/

Answer (score 2):

`typedef void (*WriteCallback)  (const byte what);` defines a [**function pointer**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-pointer-in-c/) type which takes a `const byte` and returns a `void`. It is used to easily use function pointers. Just as `uint8_t` is defined using a `typedef` as: `typedef unsigned char  uint8_t;` to be used as a easy shorthand for a 8bit width variable.

A example usage would be:

```
typedef void (*WriteCallback)  (const byte what);
void sendMsg (WriteCallback fSend, const byte * data, const byte length);

void callbackfunction(const byte what) { /*do stuff*/ }
```

With a function call:

```
sendMsg(&callbackfunction,0);
```

Internally the `sendMsg` would call the function pointed to by the `fSend` variable which in this case is `callbackfunction`.

The usage of this `typedef` makes it possbile to easily define pointers to functions and as per example switch the used write callback.

```
Writecallback funcPtr;

void switchCallback(){
    static int tmp = 0;
    if(tmp)
        funcPtr = &writecallbackA;
    else
        funcPtr = &writecallbackB;
    tmp = (tmp) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

The above usage is more easily readable and comprehendeable than:

```
void (*fun_ptr) (const byte what);
```

Comment: `&callbackfunction` defines a function pointer. The typedef defines a function pointer type.